# Apply a function with two dataframe as argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking the way to run function that take two dataframes as arguments df1 and df2.

What I want is to create a new column in df1 from the information in df2 without using a loop because my entire df1 is 3M rows and df2 700k rows.
For that I compare if the data the value of `X` of df1 is included in the `from` and the `to` of df2

I tried with apply of pandas library but I got errors like:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Here is the sample of my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9,
                         2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9],
                    'Z':['F1','F2','F2','F1','F1','F2','F2','F1','F2','F2',
                         'F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
           'from': [1.0, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6],
           'to': [1.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 2.9],
           'Z': ['F1', 'F1', 'F2', 'F1', 'F2'],
           'Y': ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo', 'zoo']
})
def asign(df1, df2):
    if df1['Z'] == df2['Z']:
        idx = np.where((df1[X] >= df2['from']) & (df1[X]<= df2['to']))[0]
        df1['Y'] = df2['Y'][idx]
        return df1

df1.groupby('Z').apply(asign, df2)
```

The output must be like:

```
>>> df1
out[0] : 
    X    Z   Y
0   1.0  F1  foo
1   1.1  F2  bar
2   1.2  F2  foobar
3   1.3  F1  foo
4   1.4  F1  foobar
5   1.5  F2  bar
6   1.6  F1  foo
7   1.7  F2  bar
```

The value of the column Y to be created in df1 is conditioned by the fact that the row belongs to the group Z either F1 or F2 and that the value of X is greater or equal to from and less than to
Please can you help me to manage this?
Thank you

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output (+ explanation)?

Comment: the question was updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Better solution using `pd.cut()`

The old solution below works well, but it might not be very efficient as it first creates a large data frame and then selects a subset of rows from it. This solution instead creates bins using [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and then merges the dataframes, directly creating the desired output.

In addition, this gives additional flexibility on how to make the merge.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9,
                         2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9],
                    'Z':['F1','F2','F2','F1','F1','F2','F2','F1','F2','F2',
                         'F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
           'bmin': [1.0,   1.5,   1.8,      2.2,   2.6],
           'bmax': [1.5,   1.8,   2.2,      2.6,   2.9],
           'Z':    ['F1',  'F1',  'F2',     'F1',  'F2'],
           'Y':    ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo', 'zoo']
})


# Adding new column to the dataframes
bins = sorted(df2.bmin.unique()) + [df2.bmax.max()]

df1.loc[:, 'bin'] = pd.cut(
    df1.X,
    bins=bins,
    labels=False,        # Makes cut return int indices for the bins
    include_lowest=True, # Otherwise 1.0 would be NaN
)
df2.loc[:, 'bin'] = pd.cut(
    0.5 * (df2.bmin + df2.bmax),
    bins=bins,
    labels=False,
    include_lowest=True,
)

# Merge on all relevant columns. Change how to 'inner' for an inner join
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["Z", "bin"], how='outer')
```

Sample of the output

```
      X   Z  bin  bmin  bmax       Y
0   1.0  F1    0   1.0   1.5     foo
1   1.3  F1    0   1.0   1.5     foo
2   1.4  F1    0   1.0   1.5     foo
3   1.1  F2    0   NaN   NaN     NaN
4   1.2  F2    0   NaN   NaN     NaN
```

## Old solution using `merge` followed by `query`

Perhaps you'd be interested in [`DataFrame.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)?

In the code below, I use `query` on a merge of the dataframes on `Z`. Note that the output data from this code differs from the one you write, but I don't see how

```
1   1.1  F2  bar
```

could result from your input data since you want both the bin and `Z` to match? What I can see, there are no bins encapsulating 1.1 in `df2` that also has `Z=F2`. Apologies if I didn't understand you question.

Note that I renamed the columns for the bin limits in `df2` as you can't use Python keywords in numexpr query.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9,
                         2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9],
                    'Z':['F1','F2','F2','F1','F1','F2','F2','F1','F2','F2',
                         'F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1','F1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
           'bmin': [1.0,   1.5,   1.8,      2.2,   2.6],
           'bmax': [1.5,   1.8,   2.2,      2.6,   2.9],
           'Z':    ['F1',  'F1',  'F2',     'F1',  'F2'],
           'Y':    ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo', 'zoo']
})

merged = pd.merge(
    df1, 
    df2,
    on='Z',
)
merged = merged.query('bmin <= X < bmax')
merged = merged.sort_values(by="X")[['X', 'Z', 'Y']]
```

Gives the output

```
      X   Z       Y
0   1.0  F1     foo
3   1.3  F1     foo
6   1.4  F1     foo
10  1.7  F1     bar
50  1.8  F2  foobar
52  1.9  F2  foobar
20  2.2  F1     foo
23  2.3  F1     foo
26  2.4  F1     foo
29  2.5  F1     foo
```

Comment: That's about what I'm looking for but using query it only selects elements that have a good merged value whereas I want the whole data set to have a value of Y so a column where all elements have a Y and that satisfies the conditions

Comment: The output I put is not right, it's just an example

Comment: I added a new solution that I think is more efficient, at least in terms of memory, using pd.bins.